# I want to format my csv file, from an excel export

Tags: excel, vba, csv, format, export

I have a problem with the date format in the new exported csv file.
If I export a range from an excel file, then the date format is dd/mm/yyyy but i need dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn.

If I changed the format in the original excel file to the right form, then the most values in the csv show the right format except the date-value e.g. 18.08.2021 00:00.

So if the time is 00:00 then only the dd/mm/yyyy format appears at that row and this format is incompatible to the database.

(i opened it in excel and in the editor and it appeared the same problem)

can someone help me?

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet, fd As FileDialog, rngTest As Range, rngExport As Range, fltr As FileDialogFilter
    Dim start As Long
    start = 2
    
    
    'Nach jeweiliger Zeit wird Datenreihe (start ab) ausgewählt
    If Time < TimeValue("11:15") Then
        Do Until Daten.Range("ov" & start) = Date + 1
        start = start + 1
        Loop
    ElseIf Time < TimeValue("11:15") Then
        Do Until Daten.Range("ov" & start) = Date + 2
        start = start + 1
        Loop
    Else: start = 2
    End If
    
    
    
   start = start + 1

    'Worksheet auf dem die Daten stehen
    Set ws = Worksheets("Daten")
     
    
    'Zelle die auf Inhalt überprüft werden soll
    Set rngTest = ws.Range("ov2")
    'Bereich der exportiert wird
    Set rngExport = ws.Range("ov" & start & ":ow10000")
'    ws.Range("ov" & start & ":ov5000").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
    If rngTest.Text <> "" Then
        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        'Filename
        fd.InitialFileName = "LG" & " " & Diagramm.Range("a5").Value & " " & "RZ" & " " & Format(Date, "mmmm") & " " & Format(Date, "yyyy") & "_" & "MW" & "_" & "ab" & " " & Daten.Range("ov" & start - 1).Value
       ' Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show filenameComplete
        With fd
            .Title = ""
            'Filterindex für CSV-Dateien ermitteln
            For i = 1 To .Filters.count
                If .Filters(i).Extensions = "*.csv" Then
                    .FilterIndex = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            'Wenn OK geklickt wurde starte Export
            If .Show = True Then
                ExportRangeAsCSV rngExport, ";", .SelectedItems(1)
                
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub

'Hier werden die Werte in eine CSV-Datei eingefügt und gespeichert
Sub ExportRangeAsCSV(ByVal rng As Range, delim As String, filepath As String)
    Dim arr As Variant, line As String, csvContent As String, fso As Object, csvFile As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set csvFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath, 2, True)
    
    arr = rng.Value 'Filter
    If IsArray(arr) Then
    
            ' um die Überschrift im CSV oben einzufügen
        Dim col As Range
        For Each col In rng.Columns
           If Len(line) > 0 Then line = line & delim
           line = line & """" & rng.Parent.Cells(1, col.column) & """"
        Next
        csvContent = line & vbNewLine
    
    
            'um die Werte ins CSV einzufügen
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            line = ""
            For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                If c < UBound(arr, 2) Then
                    line = line & """" & arr(r, c) & """" & delim
                Else
                    line = line & """" & arr(r, c) & """"
                End If
            Next
          
            csvContent = csvContent & line & vbNewLine
           
        Next
        
        csvFile.Write (csvContent)
        csvFile.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Bereich besteht nur aus einer Zelle!", vbExclamation
    End If
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set csvFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

The Range("ov").value is the date and Range("ow").value the amount (double)

Comment: Not VBA but maybe you could try this Notepad++ plug-in which can reformat datetime values https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already writing the CSV-File manually, I would suggest to introduce a function that converts your cell content as a string. You could use this routine for multiple purposes, eg format numbers (decimals, number of digits...), get rid of unwanted characters in as string (eg Newlines, semicolon, quote characers)...

Just to give you an idea:

```
Function FormatCellValue(v As Variant) As String
    If IsDate(v) Then
        FormatCellValue = Format(v, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")
    ElseIf VarType(v) = vbDecimal Then
        FormatCellValue = Format(v, "#####.00")
    ElseIf VarType(v) = vbString Then
        v = Replace(v, vbCr, " ")
        v = Replace(v, vbLf, " ")
        v = Replace(v, ";", ",")
        v = Replace(v, """", "'")
        FormatCellValue = v
    Else
        FormatCellValue = v
    End If
End Function
```

And in your existing code, simply write

```
line = line & """" & FormatCellValue(arr(r, c)) & """"
```

**Update**
If you want to write only strings with quote and dates (and numbers) without, you could add the quotes in the FormatCell-function: In the `Vartype = vbString`-branch, write

```
 FormatCellValue = """" & v & """"
```

and change the call to

```
 line = line & FormatCellValue(arr(r, c))
```

Comment: I think we could combine your and my answer together by changing my line `OutputArr(i, j) = "=""" & OutputArr(i, j) & """"` into `OutputArr(i, j) = "=""" & FormatCellValue(OutputArr(i, j)) & """"`. Which would be a genius way to include csv specific formatting into my array stringifying function.

Comment: @Toddleson: Honestly, I don't understand the idea of writing the stuff that you want to export into a formula first. Once you are in VBA, no need to return to Excel.

Comment: The workflow I usually have is that I put VBA on workbook open, let the user adjust things, and then save manually. I suppose you're right that if you're running VBA on close then what I've suggested makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Excel really sucks at formatting numbers because the internal systems keep the stored value and displayed value separately. So what you see is not what will end up in the file when you save. To force excel to actually apply the formatting to the stored value, I use quotes to turn numbers & dates into strings. Like `[A1].formula = "=""" & [A1].Value & """"` which would turn a cell containing the number 100.00 into `="100.00"` a literal string that excel can't reformat.

For your date format situation, you can do `[A1].formula = "=""" & Format([A1].Value, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn") & """"`. Which will force excel to save the cell value in the specified format and ensure the output csv is in that format.

Here is a function that I have used previously to change a 2D array of values into an array of formulas as described above.

```vb
Private Function ForceString(ByRef InputArr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim OutputArr() As Variant
    OutputArr = InputArr
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(OutputArr) To UBound(OutputArr)
        For j = LBound(OutputArr, 2) To UBound(OutputArr, 2)
            If Len(OutputArr(i, j)) < 255 Then
                OutputArr(i, j) = "=""" & OutputArr(i, j) & """"
            Else
                Dim k As Long, Tmp As String
                Tmp = "="
                For k = 1 To Len(OutputArr(i, j)) Step 255
                    Tmp = Tmp & IIf(k <> 1, "&", "") & """" & Mid(OutputArr(i, j), 1, 255) & """"
                Next k
                OutputArr(i, j) = Tmp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ForceString = OutputArr
End Function
```

The If/Else in the middle is due to the limitation in excel about a literal string inside a formula not being allowed to have more than 255 characters. In those cases, it just has to be split up into multiple strings, but the output value is still the same.

Comment: Fortunately, Excel stores numbers and formats separately. If a date would be stored as string "08/10/2021" (as it is written in a CSV file), everyone in the world would need to use the extremly strange US date format.

Comment: @FunThomas You say fortunately, I say unfortunately. :P